# azure cancel vs. remove subscription

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

I can't find how to remove subscription in portal.azure.com, there is only "cancel". Documentation says about removing from powershell - is it the same as cancel? When i cancelled it, I see it "disabled". But how to remove it completely from Azure WebUI?

[remove subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/remove-azuresubscription)

[cancel subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-how-to-cancel-azure-subscription)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it the same as cancel?

No, the command just deletes an Azure subscription from your subscription data file so Windows PowerShell can't find it. This cmdlet does not delete the subscription from Microsoft Azure, or change the actual subscription in any way.

> But how to remove it completely from Azure WebUI?

You will wait 90 days before permanently deleting your data in case you need to access it or you change your mind.